# UIScrollView performance with paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I'm trying to figure out how to improve performance in my `UIScrollView`. It is a paging scroll view with infinite scrolling. Pages are loaded two ahead and two behind of the current controller in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`. My problem is that the pages are very complex view controllers. When the paging animation completes it is around 1-2 seconds before I can page again. This varies depending on device (it is 2-3x worse on an iPad Mini than an iPad Mini with Retina).

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I believe the problem is loading the view in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`.

This is the code I call in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyPageViewController *page = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageVC"];
[self.scrollView addSubview:page.view];
```

Comment: It's difficult to help you without code. But you need take in mind if you are loading view controller in your scrollViewDidEndDecelerating (in the main thread), no matter how, how many you load in advance you will be always wait for the next (the last, the new).

Comment: Exactly. I would love to show code but this is a very complex setup spanning multiple classes. I guess I need a way to create the view controller outside of the scroll view delegate methods. I tried using ```NSNotificationCenter``` but of course this is synchronous. I also tried doing some work in the background but this isn't helping either.

Comment: Why didn't use an UIPageViewController? It make this thing automatically.

Comment: It wasn't possible unfortunately. I do a complex custom interactive animation during paging. I've tried several solutions (UIPageViewController, UINavigationController with custom transitions) but this is the only thing that gets me close to perfect. The only issue is this small delay before you can swipe to the next page.

Comment: It´s no difficult, and It will work fine, embed all your project in a CollectionView, you will have a collectionView as a main, every cell is the whole screen (you put pagingEnabled = YES). In each cell you put a complete viewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Scroll view and its subclasses are really bad at handling opacity. If there's a solid background, try to avoid subviews with opaque backgrounds if possible. It could make huge difference in scroll performance
2. Make sure that loading data for subsequent pages is made in background
3. Reuse views and view controllers. There's no need to instantiate a new view controller when you can just update model on the existing one. Make a pool of several (3-5) pages and move them around, just like UITableView do
4. You can always run Profiler to find the bottleneck

But anyway, I bet you just block the main thread (which is responsible for updating UI) with fetching data and loading new view controllers

Comment: Regarding #1 - should I turn on 'opaque' on all subviews of the UIScrollView?

Comment: @kmcgrady no, I mean if a view with solid background color, its subviews should also have a solid background, not clearColor, whenever possible. Use opaque backgrounds only if you absolutely need it

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the tips. I'm working through them now (especially #3).

Comment: Recycling made a big difference. I basically created a 'recycle' method on my VC which was a duplicate of my viewDidLoad. I then started removing code that didn't need run again and moved whatever I could to the background. It was a process of gradually increasing performance by 0.05s with each change :) There's still a little work to do but it's almost there. Thanks.